# Configure jbpm (version 7.28.0) server start with Mssql

Tags: sql-server-2005, jbpm, mssql-jdbc

I am using jbpm version 7.28.0. I need to configure it with Mssql, except connecting to the default database H2. I'm following [DB_Configuration_Note](https://docs.jboss.org/jbpm/release/7.28.0.Final/jbpm-docs/html_single/#_configuration_2) and edited \standalone\configuration\standalone.xml `<datasources>` element as below;

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:datasources:5.0">
    <datasources>
        <datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS" pool-name="ExampleDS" enabled="true" use-java-context="true">
            <connection-url>jdbc:mssql:mem:test.DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1.DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE</connection-url>
            <driver>mssql</driver>
            <security>
                <user-name>jbpm</user-name>
                <password>Jbpm@123</password>
            </security>
        </datasource>
        <xa-datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/jBPMDS" pool-name="jBPMXADS" enabled="true">
            <xa-datasource-property name="URL">jdbc:mssql:file:${jboss.server.data.dir}/jbpm-db;MVCC=TRUE</xa-datasource-property>
            <xa-datasource-class>com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDataSource</xa-datasource-class>
            <driver>mssql</driver>
            <security>
                <user-name>jbpm</user-name>
                <password>Jbpm@123</password>
            </security>
        </xa-datasource>
        <drivers>
            <driver name="h2" module="com.h2database.h2">
                <xa-datasource-class>com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDataSource</xa-datasource-class>
            </driver>
        </drivers>
    </datasources>
</subsystem>
```

But I'm getting following error.

> 16:16:35,776 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation]
>   (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed -
>   address: ([
>       ("subsystem" => "datasources"),
>       ("data-source" => "ExampleDS") ]) - failure description: {
>       "WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:" => ["jboss.jdbc-driver.mssql"],
>       "WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => [
>           "jboss.driver-demander.java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS is missing [jboss.jdbc-driver.mssql]",
>           "org.wildfly.data-source.ExampleDS is missing [jboss.jdbc-driver.mssql]"
>       ] }

I'm not sure the configuration I have done is correct. How to resolve this and connect JBPM with MSSQL?

Answer (score 0):

Both datasources are using 'mssql' driver. But this driver is not available. I will recommend to create two different drivers for H2 database and mssql database.

Answer (score 0):

ExampleDS of H2 database includes some samples of process.
javax.xml.bind.api is needed.
I wrote jbpm-sqlserver-config.cli for jbpm(7.54.0).
Try like this below.(jdk11,sqlserver2012 above)

jbpm-sqlserver-config.cli

```
embed-server --server-config=standalone.xml

try
    module add --name=com.microsoft.sqlserver --resources=drivers/mssql-jdbc-9.2.1.jre11.jar --dependencies=javax.api,javax.transaction.api,javax.xml.bind.api
catch
    echo "SQLServer module exists"
end-try

if (outcome != success) of /subsystem=datasources/jdbc-driver=sqlserver:read-resource
    /subsystem=datasources/jdbc-driver=sqlserver:add(driver-name=sqlserver,driver-module-name=com.microsoft.sqlserver,driver-xa-datasource-class-name=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerXADataSource)
end-if

if (outcome == success) of /subsystem=datasources/xa-data-source=jBPMXADS:read-resource
    /subsystem=datasources/xa-data-source=jBPMXADS:remove
end-if

xa-data-source add --name=jBPMXADS --jndi-name="java:/MSSQLXADS" --driver-name=sqlserver --user-name=jbpm --password=jbpm --xa-datasource-class=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerXADataSource --xa-datasource-properties=[ServerName=10.255.255.88, PortNumber=1433, DatabaseName=jbpm] --background-validation=false --valid-connection-checker-class-name=org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.mssql.MSSQLValidConnectionChecker


if (outcome != success) of /system-property=org.kie.server.persistence.ds:read-resource
    /system-property=org.kie.server.persistence.ds:add(value="java:/MSSQLXADS")
else
    /system-property=org.kie.server.persistence.ds:write-attribute(name=value,value="java:/MSSQLXADS")
end-if  

if (outcome != success) of /system-property=org.kie.server.persistence.dialect:read-resource
    /system-property=org.kie.server.persistence.dialect:add(value="org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect")
else
    /system-property=org.kie.server.persistence.dialect:write-attribute(name=value,value="org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect")
end-if



if (outcome != success) of /system-property=org.kie.server.id:read-resource
    /system-property=org.kie.server.id:add(value="sample-server")
else
    /system-property=org.kie.server.id:write-attribute(name=value,value="sample-server")
end-if

if (outcome != success) of /system-property=org.kie.server.controller:read-resource
    /system-property=org.kie.server.controller:add(value="http://localhost:8080/business-central/rest/controller")
else
    /system-property=org.kie.server.controller:write-attribute(name=value,value="http://localhost:8080/business-central/rest/controller")
end-if

if (outcome != success) of /system-property=org.kie.server.location:read-resource
    /system-property=org.kie.server.location:add(value="http://localhost:8080/kie-server/services/rest/server")
else
    /system-property=org.kie.server.location:write-attribute(name=value,value="http://localhost:8080/kie-server/services/rest/server")
end-if

if (outcome != success) of /system-property=org.jbpm.casemgmt.showcase.url:read-resource
    /system-property=org.jbpm.casemgmt.showcase.url:add(value="/jbpm-casemgmt")
else
    /system-property=org.jbpm.casemgmt.showcase.url:write-attribute(name=value,value="/jbpm-casemgmt")
end-if
    
stop-embedded-server
```

./jboss-cli.sh --file=jbpm-sqlserver-config.cli

You must create jbpm database on your sqlserver and give proper access right.
Read carefully "Understanding XA transactions" on ms web site.